# Find point position on a 3D Vector direction for specifix Y value.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let say I have a vector that goes through those 2 points : (0.3, 12.8, 11.2) and (1.3, 10.8, 13.4)

How can I find the position of the point for Y=0 ?

If it was in 2d I could use y=mx+b, how can I do it for a 3d vector ?

Comment: Hint: Subtract the two vectors.

Comment: Use the connection vector (-1,2,-2.2).

Comment: "*Let's say I have a vector that goes through those 2 points*"  You are using words in incorrect ways.  What you are describing is more likely a **line**, not a *vector*.

Comment: As for the *line* passing through the two points and finding the point of that line where $y=0$, write the line as $(1-t)[0.3,~12.8,~11.2] + t[1.3,~ 10.8,~ 13.4]$ by parametrizing the line by letting the first point occur at $t=0$ and the second point at $t=1$, simplifying the result, and then finding the time $t$ corresponding to the $y$ coordinate being zero and using the found value of $t$ in the resulting expression.

Comment: I'm lost, I've never use the parametric form, my linear algebra class is too many years ago. How would that work for this particular example ? I might be able to understand and generalize it afterward.